# Background não continua na área maior que a tela do navegador

Tags: css, jsf

Tenho uma tela de login:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<c:set var="context" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"></c:set>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sistema de Ouvidoria</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600;url=/ouvidoria" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${context}/resources/css/modal.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${context}/resources/css/estilo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${context}/resources/css/estiloGoogle.css" />
    <script src="${context}/resources/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.get("/ouvidoria/aviso", function(data) {
                if(data.titulo) {
                    $("#avisoTitulo").append(data.titulo);
                    $("#avisoConteudo").append(data.conteudo);
                    $(".modal").show();
                }
            }, "json" );
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="global">    
        <div class="bgSistemaOuvidoria">
            <!-- conteúdo Login -->
            <form method="post" action="${context}/login">
                <div class="conteudo">
                    <div class="logo-externa">
                        <img src="${context}/img/logo-ouvidoria.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="combo-login">
                        <div class="topoLoginBox"></div>
                        <div class="conteudoLogin">
                            <div class="mensagem">
                                <ul>
                                    <c:forEach var="error" items="${errors}">
                                        <li>
                                            <c:out value="${error}" />
                                        </li>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                    <c:choose>
                                        <c:when test="${param.logout == 'expired'}">
                                            <li>Sessão Expirada</li>
                                        </c:when>
                                    </c:choose>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panelLogin">
                                <div class="panelLoginConteudo">
                                    <div class="alingBox">
                                        <div class="loginBox">
                                            <label for="username" style="font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-size: 14px">Login:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            <br />
                                            <input type="text" name="username" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px" size="24" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="loginBoxPw">
                                            <label for="password" style="font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-size: 14px">Senha:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            <br />
                                            <input type="password" name="password" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px" size="24" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="alingButton">
                                        <div class="rSenha">
                                            <a href="${context}/recuperarsenha.xhtml">Recuperar Senha</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="dadosCadastro1">
                                            <button type="submit" style="border: none;"
                                                    class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left">
                                                <span class="ui-button-text">ACESSAR</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cadastroUsuariosOuvidoria">
                                        Não é cadastrado?
                                        <a href="${context}/pages/externo/cadastrarManifestante.xhtml">Cadastre-se</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="dadosCadastro2">
                            <div class="notch"></div>
                            <div class="botaoCadastro">
                                <img src="${context}/img/addManifestacao.png" />
                                <a href="${context}/pages/manifestacao/cadastrar.xhtml">Cadastrar Manifestação</a>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <p>
                                À Ouvidoria compete receber, examinar e encaminhar as
                                reclamações, sugestões, elogios, denúncias e solicitação de
                                informações, especialmente aquelas que demandam maior urgência.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal" id="avisoModal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" onclick="$('.modal').hide();"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="avisoTitulo"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"><div id="avisoConteudo"></div></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="$('.modal').hide();">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Estou com um problema que a tela mantém o background apenas na área da tela, caso a apareça a barra de scroll, o background fica apenas na área da apresentação original, ao rolar a barra o fundo da área revelada fica branco, e gostaria de manter o background mesmo nessas áreas.

Acho que o todo o css responsável por essa página esta ai:

```
img {
    border: 0;
}

root {
    display: block;
}

html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#bGroundPrincipal {
    background: url("../img/header_image_bg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.global {
    background: url("../img/blue_pattern.gif");
    background-color: #CACACA;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
    .conteudo {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        align-self: center;
        height: 458px;
        width: 980px;
    }

    .combo-login {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 80%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        float: right;
    }

    .logo-externa {
        height: 142px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 980px;
    }

    .logo-externa > img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 20%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        float: left;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    .conteudo {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        align-self: center;
        height: 100%;
        width: 380px;
    }

    .combo-login {
        position: absolute;
        top: 350px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        float: right;
        padding-top: 40%;
    }

    .logo-externa {
        height: 142px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .logo-externa > img {
        position: absolute;
        height: 169px;
        width: 250px;
        top: 100px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        float: left;
    }
}

.bgSistemaOuvidoria {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0%;
    height: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Já tentou usar `background-size:cover`?

Comment: @I_like_trains não havia tentado, porém testei aqui agora, e mais algumas variações que achei na net, porém nenhum resolveu

Comment: `background-attachment: local` ou `background-attachment: fixed` e tente este agora

Comment: Nenhum resolveu, é estranho o problema está quando a view fica menor que a div do painel de login, ai aparece o scroll e o que fica fora da view não pega o background

Comment: Estou pensando em fazer um `@media screen and (max-width: 380px)` com uma configuração alternativa